# Probability of a specific colored ball from a box being picked up coming from another box

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

**2** red ball from **Box-1** is taken and **transferred to** Box-2. If a ball is picked up from box-2 randomly, what is the probability of that ball being red and coming from the box-1?

Box-1 has 5 red and 4 white balls
Box-2 has 3 red and 4 white balls

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome ! I am able to *understand* exactly what you are asking, but you need to show what you have tried, and where you are stuck so that we can give appropriate help.

Comment: I hate it when users put a question for us to solve completely. This website is not an answer sheet; we are hear to help you and give suggestions, not solve entire math questions or problem.

Comment: sorry i am new here and didnt know how to add a picture. i have tried to solve this problem but not sure if it was correct. im trying to add a photo if it is possible.